# Get context from DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetimepicker

I am trying to create a Loaded event for a `DateTimePicker` where it will get the value from the `DateTime` object that the `DateTimePicker` is using as its context then convert the `DateTime` and set it back.

Code:

```
    private void dateTimePicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker)sender;
        DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)dateTimePicker.DataContext;
    }
```

XAML:

```
           <toolkit:DateTimePicker DataContext="MyDateTime" Value="{Binding Path=MyDateTime, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="dateTimePicker_Loaded" Format="SortableDateTime"/>
```

I am getting a crash on the second line of the code.
Unhandled exception: Specified cast is not valid.
The `DataContext` is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not bound the `DataContext` correctly. Use this:

```
<toolkit:DateTimePicker DataContext={Binding MyDateTime}" Value="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="dateTimePicker_Loaded" Format="SortableDateTime"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not set the `DataContext` correctly. Try

```
<toolkit:DateTimePicker DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDateTime}" Value="{Binding ,Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="dateTimePicker_Loaded" Format="SortableDateTime"/>
```

Comment: Unhandled exception: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath. InnerException: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

Comment: comma missing in the expression